# I just want some clarification on a Java Regex problem for removing leading zeros in an IP address

Tags: java, regex

I'm working to familiarize myself with regex in Java, and it's a bit of a learning curve for me.

So the solution to the problem is as follows:

```
public static String validate (String ip){
        return ip.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\.)0+(?!\\.|$)", "");
    }
```

I just need clarification on why this regex solution works.

I get that the "?" specifies zero or one instances, the "^" represents the beginning of a string, the "\." is the escape character for a period, the "$" represents the end of the line, and the ""  at the end represents deletion of a character, but I don't understand the totality of the regex. If someone could just quick walk me through what it all means together, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this regex is a tricky one, because it uses a pattern not very common : *lookahead* and *lookbehind* patterns.

> I get that the "?" specifies zero or one instances

That is true, but only when it follows a character to search for.

Here, it follows no character, as it is the first character of a group opening. It means it is a special construct. There's a dedicated javadoc subsection for it (see [1]).

In your examples, we can find two different constructs:

1. `(?<=^|\\.)`

   - This is cited in [1] as `(?<=X) X, via zero-width positive lookbehind`
   - What is this "positive lookbehind" stuff ? Source [2] defines it as `Asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is X`
   - In your case, we ask to verify that 0 is either (`|`) the first character of the input text (`^`), or is just after a `.`
2. `(?!\\.|$)`

   - [1] define it as `(?!X)   X, via zero-width negative lookahead`
   - [2] explains: `Asserts that what immediately follows the current position in the string is not X`
   - In your context, it ensures that we don't match trailing zero of a number (either the last zero or a zero that is just before a dot).

### Sources:

[1] [Oracle Pattern javadoc, *Special constructs*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special)

[2] [Regex tutorial : look around](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! You're right, it is pretty tricky. I know there's more than one way to skin a cat, so there are probably simpler solutions, but I want to understand what's going on so I'm not just lost, so your answer was really helpful and insightful! I greatly appreciate it fam!!!!